# Change value of golang C.String variable in C function

Tags: go, cgo

i want to get an int and string from C function.
int - error code, string - the data.

Tried that way:

```
package main
/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test(char *out){
  snprintf(out, sizeof out, "1234567890abcd");
  return 0;
}

*/
import "C"

import (
  "fmt"
  "unsafe"
)

func main() {
  foo := C.CString("")
  defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(foo))
  C.test(foo)
  fmt.Println("Output is: "+C.GoString(foo))
}
```

and it almost worked.

> > > Output is: 1234567

but should be: 1234567890abcd

I think that size of C.String passed to C function is 8.
But don't know how can I extend it (fixed size <> 8) or change into dynamic.

So the question is: How should I pass that variable to C?

Comment: You might want to post your C code.  Having trouble determining exactly where your problem lies.

Comment: All needed C code is in /* */ -> function test is my problem in a pill.

Comment: For reference, a somewhat related question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a research i found a solution:

```
package main


/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test(char *out, int len){
  snprintf(out, len, "1234567890123456789012345671`iknvcap9nv1-93hbf1-39b");
  return 0;

}

*/
import "C"

import (
  "fmt"
  "unsafe"
)

func main() {
  buf := make([]byte, 8192)
  C.test((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])), C.int(len(buf)))
  fmt.Println(string(buf))
}
```

To receive 'string' from C function, i had to create a slice:

```
  buf := make([]byte, 8192)
```

and pass a pointer to it:

```
  C.test((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])), C.int(len(buf)))
```

**Using C.String in that situation is not working.**

Answer (score 7):

You are calling the function `sizeof` on a pointer. The size of a pointer is 8 bytes on your computer so you are getting back a string of length 8.

I don't know all the details of how exactly you should be managing your pointer size, since i'm not that good at C but this example illustrates how to solve your immediate issue.

```
package main
/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test(char *out){
  snprintf(out, 16, "1234567890abcd");
  return 0;
}

*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    foo := C.CString("")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(foo))
    C.test(foo)
    fmt.Println("Output is: "+C.GoString(foo))
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working as expected.
When You change
snprintf(out, 16, "1234567890abcd");
into something longer than 26 chars, for example:
snprintf(out, 30, "123456789012345678901234567");
program crashes:

*** Error in `/tmp/go-build755328986/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/strings': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001f99010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d053)[0x7f3fa64f2053]
/tmp/go-build755328986/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/strings[0x436925]
======= Memory map: ========
...

Answer (score -1):

For anyone coming across this in the future, C.CString does actually work, you just can't use sizeof with a pointer as this is always 8 chars. I did it the following way:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int test(char* out){
  strcpy(out, "1234567890123456789012345671`iknvcap9nv1-93hbf1-39b");
  return 0;
}

*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    foo := C.CString("")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(foo))
    C.test(foo)
    fmt.Println("Output is: " + C.GoString(foo))
}
```

Comment: What you did here is a big "no-no" in C world. You have just overwritten some memory after the pointer's address.